# Angular2 <div> which taking full screen size

Tags: html, css, angular

Im building an Angular2 application and have the following issue which I can't seem to solve or find a solution for. Here is an image of my page:

[image]

### Code:

**content.component.html**

```
<app-header></app-header>
<div class="content">

</div>
```

**content.component.css**

```
.content{
 height: calc(100vh - 60px);
 background-color: rgb(167, 167, 167);
}
```

Header has a fixed height of 60px;

I want to give the content component a background-color and I'm looking for a `<div>` which has the following properties:

1. The `<div>` needs to fill up the whole page but not more than this (no scrollbars if not necessary).
2. The `<div>` should automatically adjust in size whenever scrollbars do arrive (when screen width is getting smaller and content pressed on top of each other).

I tried `height: calc(100vh - headercomponentHeight)` but this gives problems when the content is stacked and scrollbars pop up because the content will flow out of the `<div>`.

Comment: Can you post the code you already have?

Comment: Its a lot but I can try to simplify it to reproduce only essential parts

Comment: try changing `height: calc(100vh - 60px);` to `min-height: calc(100vh - 60px);`. When you set the `height` property it is fixing it to what you specify, which will make your content flow out of the container if it takes up more space than you specify

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this should work

```css
header {
  background: #ccc;
  height: 60px;
}

main {
  background: #ddd;
  min-height: calc(100vh - 60px);
  position: relative;
  padding: 20px;
}
```

```html
<header></header>
<main class="content">
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Massa sed elementum tempus egestas. Tempus quam pellentesque nec nam. Quis imperdiet massa tincidunt nunc pulvinar sapien et ligula ullamcorper. Blandit aliquam etiam erat velit scelerisque in dictum non consectetur. Sed cras ornare arcu dui vivamus arcu felis bibendum ut. Cursus risus at ultrices mi. Donec massa sapien faucibus et. Nulla pellentesque dignissim enim sit. Tristique sollicitudin nibh sit amet commodo nulla facilisi nullam vehicula. At urna condimentum mattis pellentesque id nibh. Diam in arcu cursus euismod quis viverra nibh. Nec feugiat nisl pretium fusce. Cras tincidunt lobortis feugiat vivamus at augue eget. Placerat vestibulum lectus mauris ultrices eros in. Bibendum at varius vel pharetra. Sed velit dignissim sodales ut eu sem integer. Enim nec dui nunc mattis.</p>
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Massa sed elementum tempus egestas. Tempus quam pellentesque nec nam. Quis imperdiet massa tincidunt nunc pulvinar sapien et ligula ullamcorper. Blandit aliquam etiam erat velit scelerisque in dictum non consectetur. Sed cras ornare arcu dui vivamus arcu felis bibendum ut. Cursus risus at ultrices mi. Donec massa sapien faucibus et. Nulla pellentesque dignissim enim sit. Tristique sollicitudin nibh sit amet commodo nulla facilisi nullam vehicula. At urna condimentum mattis pellentesque id nibh. Diam in arcu cursus euismod quis viverra nibh. Nec feugiat nisl pretium fusce. Cras tincidunt lobortis feugiat vivamus at augue eget. Placerat vestibulum lectus mauris ultrices eros in. Bibendum at varius vel pharetra. Sed velit dignissim sodales ut eu sem integer. Enim nec dui nunc mattis.</p>
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Massa sed elementum tempus egestas. Tempus quam pellentesque nec nam. Quis imperdiet massa tincidunt nunc pulvinar sapien et ligula ullamcorper. Blandit aliquam etiam erat velit scelerisque in dictum non consectetur. Sed cras ornare arcu dui vivamus arcu felis bibendum ut. Cursus risus at ultrices mi. Donec massa sapien faucibus et. Nulla pellentesque dignissim enim sit. Tristique sollicitudin nibh sit amet commodo nulla facilisi nullam vehicula. At urna condimentum mattis pellentesque id nibh. Diam in arcu cursus euismod quis viverra nibh. Nec feugiat nisl pretium fusce. Cras tincidunt lobortis feugiat vivamus at augue eget. Placerat vestibulum lectus mauris ultrices eros in. Bibendum at varius vel pharetra. Sed velit dignissim sodales ut eu sem integer. Enim nec dui nunc mattis.</p>
</main>
```